# Custom Nginx Deployment Configuration in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, volumes

Well, I there is actually two questions, 1: The Title. 2: How to access the Application deployment through the Nginx upstream.. Just Take A Look at the Following Example..

There Is An Nginx Deployment with Following Kubernetes Manifest Setup...

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment 

metadata:
  name: service-nginx-server 
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  
spec:
  selector:
     matchLabels:
      name: internal-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels: 
        name: internal-service
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: service-nginx-server 
          image: nginx:1.7.9 
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80 
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: "0.4"
              memory: "1Gi"
            requests:
              cpu: "0.4"
              memory: "1Gi"
```

And the Following Configuration for the Nginx is...

```
events {
    worker_connections 4096;
}

http {

    upstream application_upstream {
        server  APPLICATION_DEPLOYMENT_HOST:APPLICATION_DEPLOYMENT_PORT;
    }

    server {

        listen 80;
        location / {

            proxy_pass http://application_upstream;
            proxy_http_version              1.1;
            proxy_set_header   Host         $host;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade        $http_upgrade;
            
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,OPTIONS";
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true";
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*";

            if ($request_method = "OPTIONS") {
                return 200;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And Also there is an Application Manifest...

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 
kind: Deployment 

metadata:
  name: application-service 
  namespace: namespace 

  spec:
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: application-service 
    template:
      metadata: 
        labels:
          app: application-service 
      spec:
        containers:
        - name: service-application 
          image: some_image:latest
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8000
            protocol: HTTP 
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
              name: project-secrets
        restartPolicy: onFailure 
        
          livenessProbe:
            - httpGet:
                path: /healthcheck/
                port: 8000 
                protocol: HTTP  

          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: "0.5"
              memory: "3Gi"
            limits:
              cpu: "0.6"
              memory: "3Gi"
```

So the First Question is How can I Replace the Default Nginx Configuration with the Custom One, using Kubernetes `Volumes`.

And the Second is actually related to the request destination, how can I Access The Application `Deployment`, what IP and Port I Need to Specify at Nginx Upstream,
in order to forward the request to the application??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So the First Question is How can I Replace the Default Nginx
> Configuration with the Custom One, using Kubernetes Volumes.

You can use the **configmap** to store the Nginx config and **mount** it to **POD** and it will replace the existing default one you can use it with the application.

**Example**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: wordpress-site
  name: wordpress-site
  namespace: development
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wordpress-site
      tier: frontend
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: wordpress-site
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 256
          name: nginxthroughpass
          optional: false
        name: nginxconf
      - name: shared-files
        emptyDir: {}
      containers:
        - name: app
          image: <REPLACE WITH DOCKER PHP-FPM IMAGE URL>
          imagePullPolicy : IfNotPresent
          volumeMounts:
            - name: shared-files
              mountPath: /var/www/html
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: wordpress-configmap
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx
          imagePullPolicy : IfNotPresent
          volumeMounts:
          - name: shared-files
            mountPath: /var/www/html
          - mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d
            name: nginxconf
            readOnly: true
```

Ref files : https://github.com/harsh4870/Kubernetes-wordpress-php-fpm-nginx

The above example is with the Nginx with WordPress in the same container. Mounting the Nginx config at `/etc/nginx/conf.d` from configmap: `nginxconf`.

Ref file : https://github.com/harsh4870/Kubernetes-wordpress-php-fpm-nginx/blob/master/nginx-configmap.yaml

> how can I Access The Application Deployment, what IP and Port I Need
> to Specify at Nginx Upstream, in order to forward the request to the
> application??

If you mean request routing from Nginx to an application running inside the same POD you can access it over localhost and **PORT** like i have done.

If your app is running at **3000** inside Nginx config it will be `localhost:3000`, each container running in the same POD can access each other over the localhost.

**Extra note :**
In a general scenario, people use the Nginx ingress in front of the applications to route the traffic.